# How to upload an image without page refresh

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, upload

My question is plain and simple, I am trying to upload an image without a page refresh.

I have looked around the net, and yes, there are quite a few examples. Although, most of them are not what I am after. Some of them still refresh the page. Some preview the image and have a fancy uploader. I am not after anything of this kind.

I have a HTML form with a file browse. Once the user has selected their image, and the submit button is pressed, the image gets saved to the 'uploads/' section in my server.

I have found that the best ways to do this are via AJAX, PHP and through an iFrame. Although, most examples online are either not working at all, or are far to complex.

THIS IS AN ASSIGNMENT. But my teacher has stated that we can use any upload script we find online, as long as we reference it.

I am limited to Javascript (no librarys such as jquery, just plain javascript), PHP, HTML and AJAX.

All help is greatly appreciated, and I am open to all links that you provide also, since I may have missed a few.

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: If you want a hint, upload to an iFrame and handle the completion via Javascript or use some ready plugins like uploadify or any similar flash uploader

Comment: limited to javascript by your own or assignment not allowed to use jquery ?

Comment: you can simply upload to iframe by setting the target of your form to the name of the iframe, then in the iframe add a script something like "<script>window.parent.Call_Some_Function()</script>"

Comment: @xan - Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic/172760#172760

Comment: @krish - Not to sure what you mean? But yes, I am not allowed to use any Javascript librarys...

Comment: @Shehabix - I am extremely new to Javascript, PHP and AJAX, so this is all very new to me...

Comment: google it then, "How to upload to server through iframe"

Comment: @JadeMulholland [Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/209357) Show us the codes you have tried, or you risk the question getting closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, "new FormData()" and send it via Ajax. That's only works on modern browsers, if you want to support IE, use a hidden iframe as target to your form and handle it using javascript.